# How to properly use delay function

Tags: jquery

The delay function isn't working as I expect it should. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I have an overlay that I want to use. When a user clicks a link, I'd like this function to delay for 1 second and then "release", allowing the user to go to the link they clicked on. How can I do this?

```
     $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
     $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
...
      }).delay(1000);  <-- This is where I think it should go...
    });
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried both solutions offered but I can't get the overlay to hold. The screen just refreshes in about half a second. It's ignoring the setTimeout function. What I did to test the setTimeout function was the following but I don't even get the alert. I'm assuming that I would put my overlay code in place of where I have the alert(), right?

Just for clarity, what I expect to see is a 1 second delay when the .load selector is clicked then the user forwarded to the link they clicked.

```
  $('.load').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      alert();
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: What you did in your edit is attaching an event handler to the element with `load` class. If it is a link, it will redirect you and you will see no effect of `setTimeout`. You should be aware of what code you are writing - if you have any questions, let us know. But the code from the edit differs significantly from the first snippet - they both just do totally different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How `.delay()` works

From the documentation:

> `.delay()` - Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

And example usage:

```
$("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

### Solution

If you want however to delay execution of some command and it is not in the queue like the above, then just use simple JavaScript's `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
        ...
    });
}, 1000);
```

In your case this is the preferred solution, as `delay()` works only on queued items (as mentioned above). As a proof see that this is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/xaC3m/

Comment: This isn't working Tadeck. I've changed the selector from dev.first to #overlay and put that in the setTimeOut function but it isn't working. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Muzz: I showed you the solution within the "_Solution_" part of my answer. The one containing "`div.first`" was to show you the example usage, jsfiddle was supposed to show you the case when `delay()` isn't working. If you will use part of your code (`$("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");`) and add the code I gave you in _Solution_ part, you should be set. Just remember to replace `...` with anything you had as style definition. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Tadeck. I'm still new to JQuery and am still learning. I've got it though, thanks. Also, thank you for explaining it to me.

Comment: @Muzz: No problem, I am happy it helped. But keep in mind that learning JavaScript first, and then jQuery, is usually quite beneficial. Raw JavaScript is powerful, jQuery is just a layer over it, but you still need to know JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery delay function is a helper for jQuery animations. It does not delay an arbitrary operation. If you need to delay something, use setTimeout.

Following would execute the inner function after 1 second.

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#overlay").height(100); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Ekin. I've tried your code but the page refreshes and there is no delay. I can see the overlay but it isn't sticking for the 1 second interval.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I came across just a thing for this last night (which helped me out).

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

this is a plugin that allows you to either work like a timeout - e.g. do something in X ms; but it also allows you to perform a delay/sleep/wait like feature on a chain (sort of)